# Django unique_together doesn't work with ForeignKey=None

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I saw some ppl had this problem before me, but on older versions of Django, and I'm running on 1.2.1.

I have a model that looks like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
 objects = CategoryManager()

 name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
 parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('The direct parent category.'))

 class Meta:
  unique_together = ('name', 'parent')
```

Whenever i try to save in the admin a category with a parent set to None, it still works when there's another category with the SAME name and parent set to None.

Ideas on how to solve this gracefully?

Answer (score 12):

The unique together constraint is enforced at the database level, and it appears that your database engine does not apply the constraint for null values.

In Django 1.2, you can define a [clean method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for your model to provide custom validation. In your case, you need something that checks for other categories with the same name whenever the parent is None.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        """
        Checks that we do not create multiple categories with 
        no parent and the same name.
        """
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        if self.parent is None and Category.objects.filter(name=self.name, parent=None).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Another Category with name=%s and no parent already exists" % self.name)
```

If you are editing categories through the Django admin, the clean method will be called automatically. In your own views, you must call `category.fullclean()`.

Comment: The general approach looks good here, but I'm not following the logic of `if self.parent and Category.objects.filter(name=self.name).exists():` That looks to me like it is checking that the parent exists and another category with the same name exists. How is this what we want? Shouldn't this rather be something like (untested) `if self.parent == None and FolderUpload.objects.filter(name=self.name, parent=None).exists():`?

Comment: I think you're right. I would use parent_id__is null=True instead of parent=None. It probably needs an exclude () to ignore the current object as well.

Comment: I'll be away for a week, so won't be able to correct the answer. Feel free to edit it if you want / can.

Comment: Mind that this has a race condition... Another object that would fail the above validation could be created between the moment when the current validation is done and the moment when the current object is saved.

Answer (score 5):

I had that problem too and solved it by creating a supermodel with `clean` method (like Alasdair suggested) and use it as base class for all my models:

```
class Base_model(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract=True

  def clean(self):
    """
    Check for instances with null values in unique_together fields.
    """
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    super(Base_model, self).clean()

    for field_tuple in self._meta.unique_together[:]:
        unique_filter = {}
        unique_fields = []
        null_found = False
        for field_name in field_tuple:
            field_value = getattr(self, field_name)
            if getattr(self, field_name) is None:
                unique_filter['%s__isnull'%field_name] = True
                null_found = True
            else:
                unique_filter['%s'%field_name] = field_value
                unique_fields.append(field_name)
        if null_found:
            unique_queryset = self.__class__.objects.filter(**unique_filter)
            if self.pk:
                unique_queryset = unique_queryset.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            if unique_queryset.exists():
                msg = self.unique_error_message(self.__class__, tuple(unique_fields))
                raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, for those of us using PostgreSQL as our backend database engine, there will never have a fix for this issue:**

"Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.

When an index is declared unique, multiple table rows with equal indexed values are not allowed. Null values are not considered equal. A multicolumn unique index will only reject cases where all indexed columns are equal in multiple rows.

PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table. The index covers the columns that make up the primary key or unique constraint (a multicolumn index, if appropriate), and is the mechanism that enforces the constraint."

**Source:** https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/indexes-unique.html