# How come in Django, uniques are not holding up?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240,null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adinfo = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True,blank=True)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True,blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('title','adinfo'),)


mysql> select * from mo_a where id = 1113\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        id: 1113
     title: Tides Tavern
      body: Come in and enjoy the morning sun or a nice sunset with breakfast, lunch or dinner. Find a seat, put your feet up &amp; enjoy. Click here!
    adinfo: NULL
       url: 
       img: http://creative.ak.fbcdn.net/v41818/flyers/125/47/13039135731061564765_1_89254352.jpg
created_at: 2011-07-08 00:41:18
updated_at: 2011-07-08 00:41:18
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql> select * from mo_a where id = 1114\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        id: 1114
     title: Tides Tavern
      body: Come in and enjoy the morning sun or a nice sunset with breakfast, lunch or dinner. Find a seat, put your feet up &amp; enjoy. Click here!
    adinfo: NULL
       url: 
       img: http://creative.ak.fbcdn.net/v41818/flyers/125/47/13039135731061564765_1_89254352.jpg
created_at: 2011-07-08 00:41:22
updated_at: 2011-07-08 00:41:22
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Is this normal? As you can see, I have title and adinfo uniqued...I did NOT want #1114 to be inserted. But it did. How do I remove all the duplicates in the database?

Comment: Is your question about how to enforce a uniqueness constraint in Django, or how to remove a large amount of duplicates in MySQL? If you want the answer to both questions, you should ask a second question for the duplicate removal (after checking to see if it has been asked before).

Comment: did you try with adinfo not NULL? just out of curiosity, since django treats "NULL" value like unique no matter how many times you repeat it throu the database. So maybe it's causing some problems... just do a test populating the adinfo field

Comment: "[For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html)".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django unique_together doesn't work with ForeignKey=None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488264/django-unique-together-doesnt-work-with-foreignkey-none)

Comment: DrTyrsa is right. MySQL doesn't think that NULL is the same as NULL, so as far as it is concerned, the unique index is satisfied. In MySQL's world, title != title, adinfo != adinfo, therefore there's no violation of the unique constraint.

Comment: @DrTyrsa You should just post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The way you specified your UNIQUE constraint, you're stating that you don't allow insertion of duplicates for pairs.

As you specified, you would be able to insert the pairs:

```
(1113, 'Tides Tavern') and (1114, 'Tides Tavern')
```

or

```
(1113, 'Roman road') and (1113, 'Tides Tavern')
```

but not:

```
(1113, 'Tides Tavern') and (1113, 'Tides Tavern')
```

In other words, from Postgresql docs: **"A multicolumn unique index will only reject cases where all of the indexed columns are equal in two rows."**