# Unique_together doesn't work if a field is null. How to constrain it?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this

```
class ProductCode( models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together=[('code','customer'), ] 
    customer = models.ForeignKey( 'customers.Customer', models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, )
    code = models.CharField( max_length = 20)
    product = models.ForeignKey( Product, models.CASCADE, )
    ...
```

The trouble is that if `customer is None` (DB null) then the constraint is not enforced. It lets me store rows/objects with, say,  (code='foo', customer=None) multiple times.  I have found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488264/django-unique-together-doesnt-work-with-foreignkey-none) which suggests that the problem is un-fixable for Postgres users.

Is there any way to enforce this constraint with the (relatively) new `Meta` `constraints`? I am finding [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#constraints) a bit hard to fathom.

Or do I have to implement a placeholder customer to attach "default" product codes to?

Or, another way would be to prepend a textual representation of `customer` to `code` and then just make it `unique=True` and use `__startswith=` and `__contains` lookups where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior: in a database `NULL` is quite special in the sense that `NULL` is not equal not `NULL`.

You can add a second uniqness constraint that is used when the other field is `NULL`, so:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class ProductCode(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'customers.Customer',
        models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('code', 'customer'), name='code_customer_unique1'
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('code',),
                condition=Q(customer=None),
                name='code_customer_unique2',
            ),
        ]
```

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly, and I now better understand meta constraints!